# Does deleting an item from mailbox permanently using (shift+delete) will delete the extendedProperty attached to that item in exchange

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

We have created items with extendedProperty but we didn't create the extendedProperty the right way, We are looking for ways to clean up those extendedProperties ..so we are wondering if deleting the items permanently from mail box using (Shift+delete) will also delete the corresponding extendedProperties ? 
by the questions below

[Quetion1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847448/how-to-retrieve-the-extendedproperties-associated-with-emails-in-the-sent-folder/50848122#50848122)

[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807362/invalid-named-property/50807593)

We came to know that we will not be able to access the extended properties by the ewsapi and delete that's why we are looking at alternative ways to free up the namespaces for the extendedProperty we created

It will be of great help if anyone could point us in the right direction to clean up the extendedProperties without the uid with which they are created

Answer (score 1):

The item will be deleted, but Exchange will keep the property definition. Which means you can run out of available named properties (0xFFFF max).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry ! that's what we found from our testing too,  so could you please suggest a way for us to delete the property definition from the exchange ?

Comment: There is no documented way to do that.